# How do I prevent Stripe from counting customers whose card was declined?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am having an issue that Stripe will count a new customer even if the card is declined. I have not figured out a way to prevent Stripe from counting these users in their Dashboard.  (Technically it is a NEW customer, but they have no active subscription or charge on their card.)

However, my web application handles these just fine and it just asks the user to put in their credit card information again due to a declined credit card.

```
try{    
$cusresp = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "description" => "Customer $membertbl[email], $membertbl[name]",
   "email" => $membertbl[email], 
  "source" => $striptoken // obtained with Stripe.js
));
}
```

If this response has no catch exceptions, I then use [create subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create) and proceed normally.

Even if I go to the dashboard and delete this customer, the Stripe Dashboard still counts them.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "will count a new customer" --- if `\Stripe\Customer::create()` call succeeds the customer will exist on your account and from Stripe's perspective appear in Customer list endpoints, even if no charges or subscriptions exist on the Customer and there is no way to change that. If you're only interested in customers who have subscriptions, I'd look at https://dashboard.stripe.com/subscriptions (or the list subscriptions endpoint in the API)

Comment: @duck

By "will count as a new customer" I mean that the Stripe dashboard analytics will list that person as a new customer, even though Stripe knows the charge was declined. 
 This can have a pretty big impact on the analytics for real customers vs failed customer attempts. 

So it sounds like this is just how Stripe works and there isn't much I can do about it.

Comment: In all these cases Stripe will return a `customer_id`, which you can store and query based on the email they gave you. This way you can save the create call, and only make it if it's necessary. You can also go back and [delete the unwanted customer records](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/delete) through the API.